# SQL Server - Aggregate data by minute over multiple days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time, data-warehouse

### Context

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

There is a database table "Raw_data", that contains the status of a machine, together with it's starting time. There are several machines and each one writes it's status to the database multiple times per minute.

To reduce the data volume I'm trying to aggregate the data into 1-Minute chunks to save it for further analysis. Due to a capacity constraint, I want to execute this transition-logic every few minutes (e.g. scheduled SQL Server Agent Job), delete the raw data and just keep the aggregated data.

To simplify the example, let's assume "Raw_data" looks something like this:

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id ║ fk_machine ║ status ║     created_at      ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║       2222 ║      0 ║ 2020-08-19 22:15:00 ║
║  2 ║       2222 ║      3 ║ 2020-08-19 22:15:30 ║
║  3 ║       2222 ║      5 ║ 2020-08-19 23:07:00 ║
║  4 ║       2222 ║      1 ║ 2020-08-20 00:20:00 ║
║  5 ║       2222 ║      0 ║ 2020-08-20 00:45:00 ║
║  6 ║       2222 ║      5 ║ 2020-08-20 02:20:00 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Also there are database tables "Dim_date" and "Dim_time", that look something like that:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╗
║ datekey  ║ date_iso8601 ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 20200101 ║ 2020-01-01   ║
║ 20200102 ║ 2020-01-02   ║
║ ...      ║ ...          ║
║ 20351231 ║ 2035-12-31   ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╝

╔═════════╦══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ timekey ║ time_iso ║ min_lower_bound ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1       ║ 00:00:01 ║ 00:00:00        ║
║ 2       ║ 00:00:02 ║ 00:00:00        ║
║ ...     ║ ...      ║ ...             ║
║ 80345   ║ 08:03:45 ║ 08:03:00        ║
║ ...     ║ ...      ║ ...             ║
║ 134504  ║ 13:45:04 ║ 13:45:00        ║
║ 134505  ║ 14:45:05 ║ 13:45:00        ║
║ ...     ║ ...      ║ ...             ║
║ 235959  ║ 23:59:59 ║ 23:59:59        ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

The result should look like this:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦════════╦═══════════════╗
║ date_iso8601 ║ min_lower_bound ║ fk_machine ║ status ║ total_seconds ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 22:15:00        ║ 2222       ║ 0      ║ 30            ║
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 20:15:00        ║ 2222       ║ 3      ║ 30            ║
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 20:16:00        ║ 2222       ║ 3      ║ 60            ║
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 20:17:00        ║ 2222       ║ 3      ║ 60            ║
║ ...          ║ ...             ║ ...        ║ ...    ║ ...           ║
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 23:06:00        ║ 2222       ║ 3      ║ 60            ║
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 23:07:00        ║ 2222       ║ 5      ║ 60            ║
║ 2020-08-19   ║ 23:08:00        ║ 2222       ║ 5      ║ 60            ║
║ ...          ║ ...             ║ ...        ║ ...    ║ ...           ║
║ 2020-08-20   ║ 00:19:00        ║ 2222       ║ 5      ║ 60            ║
║ 2020-08-20   ║ 00:20:00        ║ 2222       ║ 1      ║ 60            ║
║ 2020-08-20   ║ 00:21:00        ║ 2222       ║ 1      ║ 60            ║
║ ...          ║ ...             ║ ...        ║ ...    ║ ...           ║
║ 2020-08-20   ║ 00:44:00        ║ 2222       ║ 1      ║ 60            ║
║ 2020-08-20   ║ 00:45:00        ║ 2222       ║ 0      ║ 60            ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩════════╩═══════════════╝
```

---

### Attempt

To calculate the duration of each status per minute I used an [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) to fetch the starting date and time from the next status in the database table, then joined with the dimension tables and aggregated the result.

```sql
WITH CTE_MACHINE_STATES(START_DATEKEY, 
                        START_TIMEKEY, 
                        FK_MACHINE, 
                        END_DATEKEY, 
                        END_TIMEKEY)
     AS (SELECT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CREATED_AT, 112) AS INT), -- ISO: yyyymmdd
                CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), READING_TIME, 108), ':', '')), 
                FK_MACHINE, 
                STATUS, 
                CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), LEAD(CREATED_AT, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY FK_MACHINE
                ORDER BY CREATED_AT), 112) AS INT),
                CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), LEAD(CREATED_AT, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY FK_MACHINE
                ORDER BY CREATED_AT), 108), ':', ''))
         FROM RAW_DATA)
     SELECT DATE_ISO8601, 
            MIN_LOWER_BOUND, 
            FK_MACHINE, 
            STATUS, 
            SUM(1) AS TOTAL_SECONDS -- Duration
     FROM CTE_MACHINE_STATES
     CROSS JOIN DIM_DATE
     CROSS JOIN DIM_TIME
     WHERE TIMEKEY >= START_TIMEKEY AND 
           TIMEKEY < END_TIMEKEY AND 
           END_TIMEKEY IS NOT NULL AND -- last entry per machine and status
           DATEKEY BETWEEN START_DATEKEY AND END_DATEKEY
     GROUP BY FK_MACHINE, 
              STATUS, 
              DATE_ISO8610, 
              MIN_LOWER_BOUND
     ORDER BY DATE_ISO8610, 
              MIN_LOWER_BOUND;
```

### The Problem

If the status lasts past midnight it won't be aggregated correctly. For example the status at id = 3 in "Raw_data" starts at 23:07 and ends on 00:20 the next day. Here, timekey is greater than end_timekey, so the status get's excluded from the resulting table by the filter `TIMEKEY < END_TIMEKEY`. I haven't come up with a solution on how to change the join-condition to include such long-lasting states, but get the expected result.

PS: I already wrote, that normally status-updates are happening every several seconds. Thus, the problem only occurs in edge cases, e.g. if a machine get's turned off.

---

### Solution

Unfortunately I did not receive an answer on how to get the expected result using the date- and time dimension tables. But dnoeth's approach using a recursive CTE is good, so I went with it:

```sql
WITH cte_outer AS (
    SELECT fk_machine,
           status,
           created_at,
           DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, '2000', created_at), '2000') AS min_lower_bound, --truncates seconds from start time
           LEAD(created_at) OVER(PARTITION BY fk_machine ORDER BY created_at) AS end_time
    FROM raw_data
),
    cte_recursive AS (
        SELECT fk_machine,
               status,
               min_lower_bound,
               end_time,
               CASE
                 WHEN end_time > DATEADD(minute, 1, min_lower_bound)
                 THEN DATEDIFF(s, created_at, DATEADD(minute, 1, min_lower_bound))
                 ELSE DATEDIFF(s, created_at, end_time)
               END AS total_seconds
        FROM cte_outer

        UNION ALL

        SELECT fk_machine,
               status,
               DATEADD(minute, 1, min_lower_bound), -- next time segment (minute)
               end_time,
               CASE
                 WHEN end_time >= DATEADD(minute, 2, min_lower_bound)
                 THEN 60
                 ELSE DATEDIFF(s, DATEADD(minute, 1, min_lower_bound), end_time)
               END
        FROM cte_recursive
        WHERE end_time > DATEADD(minute, 1, min_lower_bound)
)
SELECT min_lower_bound,
       fk_machine,
       status,
       total_seconds
FROM cte_recursive
ORDER BY  fk_machine, 
          min_lower_bound
```

Comment: I worked many years in industry with this kind of problem regularly arising (furthermore, I'm french so we have the daylight saving problem twice a year...)
If it's possible for you depending on yourjob configuration / policies, take a look at a timeseries database such as InfluxDb, you'll be amazed.

Comment: @Romka, thanks for your reply and the advise. Unfortunately changing the DBMS is not an option, at the moment.

Comment: Please describe more clear your goal. The presented example "aggregate" six rows in approximatelly 240 (minute) rows - which is not realy a *volume reduction*. What is wrong with a trivial aggregation of total seconds grouped by status, machine and a (starting) minute?

Comment: @Parfait: Sorry, I forgot adding joins in the code snippet. Now, I edited my question.

Comment: @Marmite Bomber: I simplified the example to show the problem I got when trying to aggregate states than span over multiple days. The original database get's filled by status updates in an interval of aprox. 3 sec. per machine as long as they are not turned off. The aggregated data will be used for further analysis, e.g. the occupancy rate of the machines.

Comment: My point was *if the machine is off say for an hour* do you realy want to "aggregate" 60 minute rows with the last available state? Isn't better / enough to store only the last available minute along with the duration of 3600 sec?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: Good point. The total_seconds attribute (duration) is the proportion of the status per time_segment. in the example one time segment equals one minute. If there would be a 15min_lower_bound in dim_time, you could group by that and thus easily aggregate in buckets of 15 min, if you never need more precise (greater granularity) data. I think, if the database table would contain a row "2020-08-19 | 23:07:00 | 2222 | 3 | 4380" (total seconds between 23:07 -> 00:20) the data in the table would be inconsistent.

Comment: @Parfait: Thanks for your feedback. I edited my question and added explicit cross join clauses to make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: Could I use a tally table to do this?  It's easier and it wouldn't require your DIM tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use-case for a recursive CTE, increasing `created_at` by one minute per recursion:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select fk_machine
     ,status  
     ,start_minute
     ,end_time
     ,case
        when end_time > dateadd(minute, 1,start_minute)
        then datediff(s, created_at, dateadd(minute, 1,start_minute)) 
        else datediff(s, created_at, end_time )
      end as seconds
   from
    (
      select fk_machine
        ,status
        ,created_at 
        ,dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, created_at), 0) as start_minute
        ,lead(created_at)
         over (PARTITION BY fk_machine
               order by created_at) as end_time
      from tab
    ) as dt
 
   union all
 
   select fk_machine
     ,status
     ,dateadd(minute, 1,start_minute)
     ,end_time
     ,case
        when end_time >= dateadd(minute, 2,start_minute)
        then 60
        else datediff(s, dateadd(minute, 1,start_minute), end_time)
      end
    from cte
    where end_time > dateadd(minute, 1,start_minute)
 )
select * from cte
order by 1,3,4;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4a700eb5d4cce6537458a4822b67e64)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go with that solution. Added it as the accepted answer, although it does not use the dimention tables (which I did not state as a requirement). The `partition by`-part when fetching the end time of the current status get's important, when there is more than one machine.

Comment: Of course, without `PARTITION BY fk_machine` it will not work as expected, I forgot to add that. If you want the FKs to your dimension tables, you can simply use the your initial CASTs.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, concatenating the keys to a single datetime isn’t as costly as it might seem. Then you can call DATEDIFF() to check for positive, negative, absolute, values for the comparison. I’ve run something similar translating instantaneous data to minute aggregates across multiple decades, and datediff really makes the difference. However, this would do much better if you simply pull the raw data and perform the calculations in a language with a good datetime library. SQL is always the answer until it isn’t.

What’s likely causing one of the problems here is the following statement:

```
WHERE TIMEKEY >= START_TIMEKEY AND 
              TIMEKEY < END_TIMEKEY AND 
              END_TIMEKEY IS NOT NULL AND 
              DATEKEY BETWEEN START_DATEKEY AND END_DATEKEY
```

If the date and time aren’t separated, you can say:

```
WHERE DateTimeKey >= START_DateTimeKey AND 
              DateTimeKey < END_DateTimeKey AND 
              END_TIME-KEY IS NOT NULL
```

If you are trying to aggregate by a time value, it would be helpful to eliminate any timekey table, that may be another source of problems.  It may be a good idea to replace the timekey table with a recursion and a period duration. You will also need to account for these conditions:

End time of the event must always be after the start time of the aggregate period start time:

```
DateDiff(second, Period_Start_Time, Event_End) > 0
```

Start time of the event must always be before the end of the aggregate period end time:

```
DateDiff(second, Period_Start_Time, Event_Start) <= @Period_Duration
```

There are several ways to distribute the event data across the periods, but datediff helps with linear distribution as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no need to concatenate the date- and timekey, since the starting time of the status ("created_at" in Raw_data) is in datetime-format. Could you please be more precise or post sample code on how you would aggregate by minute, after we calculated the duration of each status via [Datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)?